# Call Stored Function in raw query laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

How do I take the string "/ Muh Ghazali Akbar" in this array.?

```
array (2) {[0] => object (stdClass) # 218 (1) {["selectPath (12)"] => string (18) "/ Muh Ghazali Akbar"}
```

in my raw query

```
$path = DB::table('folders')->select(DB::raw('selectPath('.$folder->id.')'))->get();

var_dump($path);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, but probably this is what you mean and need: `DB::raw('selectPath('.$folder->id.') as path')`

Comment: what the mean "as path".? sir :)

Comment: It's simple sql alias, then you get it `$path[0]->path`

Comment: Owhh.. is work ^_^ thank you ^_^